# AngularJs | ng-click not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-handling, dom-events, angularjs-ng-click

I can see no apparent reason why the `ng-click` shouldn't work, however it does not fire when clicking the element it is bound to.

There are two elements that will be rendered. Each one has an icon X on on the top right of its div which should fire `deletePreview`. This will lead currently to the deletion of the first item of `linkPreviews`. When invoking this method by `$timeout` e.g., it works as expected. Trying to click on the icon however is not working.

I'm glad for any ideas.

```js
(function (angular) {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('commons.ui')
    .directive('linkPreview', linkPreview)
    .controller('LinkPreviewController', LinkPreviewController);

  function linkPreview() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: 'link-preview/link-preview.html',
      scope: {},
      require: 'ngModel',
      bindToController: {
        focusVar: '=?',
        placement: '@'
      },
      controller: 'LinkPreviewController',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl'
    };
  }

  function LinkPreviewController($log, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.deletePreview = deletePreview;

    vm.linkPreviews = [
      {
        image: {
          fileId: 'f616157b-223d-46ff-ba87-c16d10e83ed6',
          senderId: '1ae6f889-f27e-4466-a0a9-021923704097'
        },
        title: 'Title',
        description: 'This is an integrated platform for your official company news, social collaboration and team messaging.',
        url: 'http://www.sample.com/en/tour',
        tld: 'sample.com'
      },
      {
        image: '',
        title: 'Hacker News',
        description: 'News for the technically interested',
        url: 'https://news.ycombinator.com/',
        tld: 'news.ycombinator.com'
      }
    ];

    function deletePreview() {
      $log.info('should be deleted');
      vm.linkPreviews.splice(0, 1);
    }
  }
})(angular);
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="linkPreview in $ctrl.linkPreviews">
    <div class="link-preview">
        <div class="link-preview-delete pull-right">
            <div class="link-preview-delete pull-right">
                <span class="link-preview-delete-button" ng-click="$ctrl.deletePreview()">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-close img-close"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        ..
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you see any `console.log`? Or error? What if you add the `ng-click` to the `<div class="link-preview-delete pull-right">` part ; any difference? Do you have the possibility to create a JsFiddle / Plunkr / ... ?

Comment: No error, no console log. Will try for Plunkr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is a bug in AngularJS? Or I indeed misused it.

In my example, the top html element of the directive is `<div ng-repeat="linkPreview in $ctrl.linkPreviews">`, meaning that multiple divs will be added on the same hierarchy level.

When wrapping this in another div, as the example of @anoop showed, it'll all of a sudden work. What I don't understand yet is, why is the array of `vm.linkPreviews` is always attached to the controller, however the function `vm.deletePreviews` will only work when it is wrapped in one top div.

Working HTML code:

```html
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="linkPreview in $ctrl.linkPreviews">
        <div class="link-preview">
            <div class="link-preview-delete pull-right">
            <span class="link-preview-delete-button" ng-click="$ctrl.deletePreview()">
              <i class="zmdi zmdi-close img-close"></i>
            </span>
            </div>
            <div class="link-preview-image-wrapper">
                <div class="link-preview-image">
                    <coyo-image-reference ng-if="linkPreview.image"
                                          file-id="::linkPreview.image.fileId"
                                          sender-id="::linkPreview.image.senderId"
                                          size-definitions="{'default': 'S', 'screen-lg': 'S'}"></coyo-image-reference>
                    <div class="link-preview-icon" ng-if="!linkPreview.image">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-globe"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="link-preview-text-wrapper">
                <div class="link-preview-line">
                    <span class="link-preview-title" ng-bind="::linkPreview.title"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="link-preview-line">
                    <span class="link-preview-description" ng-bind="::linkPreview.description"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="link-preview-line">
                <span class="link-preview-url">
                    <a href="{{ ::linkPreview.url }}" target="_blank">{{ ::linkPreview.tld }}</a>
                </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `empty dependency` to your module, Like:

```
 angular.module('commons.ui', [])
```

and, have to use `controller as` syntax(if not used) in HTML, Like:

```
ng-controller="LinkPreviewController as $ctrl"
```

Working Demo :

```js
angular
  .module('commons.ui', [])
  .directive('coyoLinkPreview', linkPreview)
  .controller('LinkPreviewController', LinkPreviewController);

function linkPreview() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'app/commons/ui/components/link-preview/link-preview.html',
    scope: {},
    require: 'ngModel',
    bindToController: {
      focusVar: '=?',
      placement: '@'
    },
    controller: 'LinkPreviewController',
    controllerAs: '$ctrl'
  };
}

function LinkPreviewController($log, $timeout) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.deletePreview = deletePreview;

  vm.linkPreviews = [{
    image: {
      fileId: 'f616157b-223d-46ff-ba87-c16d10e83ed6',
      senderId: '1ae6f889-f27e-4466-a0a9-021923704097'
    },
    title: 'Go COYO',
    description: 'COYO is an integrated platform for your official company news, social collaboration and team messaging.',
    url: 'http://www.coyoapp.com/en/tour',
    tld: 'coyoapp.com'
  }, {
    image: '',
    title: 'Hacker News',
    description: 'News for the technically interested',
    url: 'https://news.ycombinator.com/',
    tld: 'news.ycombinator.com'
  }];

  function deletePreview() {
    console.log('clicked');
    $log.info('should be deleted');
    vm.linkPreviews.splice(0, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="commons.ui" ng-controller="LinkPreviewController as $ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="linkPreview in $ctrl.linkPreviews">
    <div class="link-preview">
      <div class="link-preview-delete pull-right">
        <div class="link-preview-delete pull-right">
          <span class="link-preview-delete-button" ng-click="$ctrl.deletePreview()">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-close img-close">spanToClick</i>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:**

In your directive you are using `scope:{}`, which creates `isolated scope`, So your code doesn't work.

Now further `ng-repeat` create `new child scope`, So your `div gets repeated` but internal logic of `ng-repeat` like delete click is under `new child scope` , So it doesn't work.

If you'll do `$parent.$ctrl` then it will point to parent and will work.

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CVQCtpYJXFRNrf55bOft?p=preview)

Overall easiest fix is to remove isolated scope from directive.  `scope: {}`

Comment: Defining the controller like 

     `ng-controller="LinkPreviewController as $ctrl"`

actually does make my code work. However now I'm curious how the binding in the function does fail. 

    `controller: 'LinkPreviewController',
    controllerAs: '$ctrl'`

I mean the ng-repeat gets rendered so why does not the ng-click work?

Comment: @Daniel : In your directive you are using `scope:{}`, which creates isolated scope, So your code doesn't work. because `ng-repeat` created new child scope. See my updated answer

Comment: @Daniel : did the updated answer solved your problem, you can accept answer if solved, could help others as well. Just going through very old answers.. :-D

Answer (score 0):

You wrong the function declaration in controller.

To use function from controller you need to set it like

```
this.deletePreview
```

or

```
$scope.deletePreview
```

(in this last case you haven't to write `$ctrl` in the `ng-click` view. Remember to inject `$scope`!).

Comment: I would expect that the lines 
    
    var vm = this;
    vm.deletePreview = deletePreview;

equal this.deletePreview